# Formal deformation theory

Tags: deformation-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

I found the following argument in more than one article:
Let $X_0$ be a complex space and define the functor $F:Art \to Sets$ s.t. $F(A)=\{\text{Isomorphism classes of deformations of X_0 over A}\}$.
Let $(X",A"),(X',A'), (X,A)$ deformations of $X$ and consider 2 maps $A"\to A$ and $A' \to A$ such that the first one is surjective, so we can consider $A' \times_{A} A"$. Then a deformation over $A' \times_{A} A"$ is $Y=(X_0,\mathcal{O}_{X'} \times_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_{X"})$. Can someone explain to me what is Y? Suppose that $X=V(f)$ for some $f\in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \dots, x_n]$, how I compute Y?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it is not compiling properly.

Comment: I fixed your formatting.

Comment: Can't compute $Y$ unless specify $X'$ and $X''$.  Meaning of $Y$ is that underlying top. space is $X$, and ring of functions over open $U$ is fiber product ring $O_ {X'}(U) \times_ {O_ X(U)} O_ {X''}(U)$ (makes sense since $X'$ and $X''$ have same underlying top. space as $X$).  Good exercise to check $Y$ really is a complex-analytic space and that natural $A' \times_A A''$-algebra structure on its structure sheaf makes it flat over $A' \times_A A''$. Good behavior of flatness under "fiber product" construction is explained in Schlessinger's first paper on def. theory (from his thesis). 

Comment: I think of $Y$ as the gluing of the two deformations $X'$ and $X''$ along $X$.

Simplistic example: $A'=k[\epsilon],A''=k[\delta]$ then
the fibered product is $k[\epsilon,\delta]/(\epsilon.\delta)$ an infinitesimal coordinate cross.

Comment: This is really a question about fiber products, not deformation theory.

Comment: does someone has any reference about that?

Comment: Reference about specifically which thing mentioned above?  Near the end of Schlessinger's first paper on deformation theory (where he introduces his criterion) he gives a discussion about this ring-theoretic fiber product construction and its relation with flat deformations.  Is that what you want to see?

Comment: I was thinking something more like if I know an equation for X,X" and X', how can I get one for Y?does this make sense?